# Have the recipient name in the body of email workflow when sending the email to a group in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I need to send an email workflow in Sharepoint designer when a new document is uploaded. But i want the body of the email with the name of the recipient.

For example, the email is going to be send to the `GROUP_ABC` and there are 3 people in that group, `allan`, `rob`, and `john`. And the email has to say: "Dear  **-Name of the person in the group-**, there is a new document" blabla..

How can I do that in SharePoint Designer 2010? I think it's simple but i can't figure it out.

Thanks in advice

Comment: I take the view that an automated email from a system isn’t personal in nature and therefore the salutation is meaningless and a little disingenuous. I just use “Hello,” instead. Never had any complaints and it avoids headaches like this one.

Comment: Of course I know that, that's what I actually do, but I'd like to do a 'personal' email so that's the reason of my question, thanks